# How can I use routing in ReactJs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, iis, routes, react-router-dom

I used HashRouter from react-router-dom.
When I use Router pages are
not found. 
what is the best way to remove HashRouter from URL? 
My server side project is asp.net MVC and Use webapi2.
IIS6

Comment: Use `BrowserRouter`, which will you get from the same package.

Comment: Also see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/hashrouter-vs-browserrouter

Answer (score 1):

In App.js file -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './component/header/header'
import Test from './component/test/test'
import Speaking from './component/test/speaking/speaking'
import Demo from './component/test/speaking/demo/demo'

 class App extends Component {
   render () {
      return (
          <Router>
             <div >
          <Header />
          <Switch>
             <Route path='/' component={Demo} />
             <Route path='/test' component={Test} />
             <Route path='/Speaking' component={Speaking } />
          </Switch>
            </div>
         </Router>
       )
      }
     }

    export default App
```