# when page refresh "404 - File or directory not found."

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

my react app is working locally but after the deploy, I faced the problem when I press any button there is no problem but if I want to refresh I see that problem "404 - File or directory not found."

I found this solution:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

**Configure Your Server**

*"Your server must be ready to handle real URLs. When the app first loads at / it will probably work, but as the user navigates around and then hits refresh at /accounts/23 your web server will get a request to /accounts/23. You will need it to handle that URL and include your JavaScript application in the response."*

But I don't know how can I do this
I try something but it doesn't work

Comment: if you are serving with nginx redirect all requests to index.html, that will fix the issue. in that way your app will get all the requests

Answer (score 1):

**TRY**

1. **npm run build**, this will create build folder inside your project root folder
2. **if you want to deploy to remote server** just transfer that build
   folder.
3. **npx serve -s build** on windows, if you are using mac kindly see if it is still npx.
4. then try to refresh every path of it

**hope this works, happy coding.**

Answer (score 0):

Since the server cannot find the static content in the directory (i.e. not found the file /tomcat/accounts/23), it will give you 404 unless you have additional route handling.

In React routing I think you can try with `HashRouter`

See more details here:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

[HashRouter vs BrowserRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/hashrouter-vs-browserrouter)