# Page not found error when refresh page after deployed react app to IIS server

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router-dom, reloading, custom-error-pages

I deploy a React app to IIS and it works well but when I press F5 to reload the page, it shows 404 error page.
I have created a web.config file to root folder in server
Is there anyone can help me so I can reload the page after deployed to IIS without this error?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It almost indicates you missed the rewrite rules to route everything back to the index page. You can find a lot of articles from search engines like https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373134/when-page-refresh-404-file-or-directory-not-found same topic