# react-router routing problem with component not refreshing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, history

I am trying to use `history.push` method in my redux react app. Its working fine but the problem is my component won't change, do you guys know why?

**route.js:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { history } from '../helper/history'

export default class route extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/error" component={Error} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Redux **action.js** where a history is called, this is where I dispatch my actions:

```
export const loginRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: userType.LOGIN_REQUEST,
  }
}

export const loginSuccess = () => {
  return {
    type: userType.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  }
}

export const loginFailure = () => {
  return {
    type: userType.LOGIN_FAILURE,
  }
}

export const fetchUser = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginRequest)
    axios
      .post(env.API_URL + 'login', { email: data.email, password: data.password })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data.user))
        history.push({
          pathname: '/profile',
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(loginFailure(error))
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: even if I add some profile component and route it showing the same issue ` <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />`. `history.push('/profile')` is working but my component wont change unless I refresh's my page

Comment: `import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are providing `history` props, you should use `Router`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56707885/2873538), [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) and [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter):

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

instead of

<s>`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'`</s>