# How do I save state of a form in a component using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a SPA that has multiple routes. Each of these routes are parent components to 2 children (a form component and a table component, that displays data fetched from an API).
The goal is to be able to come back to the form with the fields populated as before if a user navigates away from it.

Here's what I have so far. My `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`App.js`

```
return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                <Route path="/onDemandProductSearch" component={OnDemandProductSearch} />
            </Switch>
        );
```

`OnDemandProductSearch.js` component has 2 children as mentioned above. I only display the form and once parameters on the form are selected, display the table with the fetched data.

```
class OnDemandProductSearch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            products: [],
            isSearched: false
        };
    };

    onFiltersSelected = (products, queryParams) => {
        this.setState({
            products: products,
            isSearched: true
        });
        
        this.props.history.push({
            search: queryParams
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.props.history.location.search === "" ?
                    <OnDemandProductSearchMenu onFiltersSelected={this.onFiltersSelected} /> :
                    <InstanceList products={this.state.products} />}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

`OnDemandProductSearchMenu.js`,

```
fetch(`${apiURL}/simple-products/search`, {
            // body here
            })
        })
            .then((response) => {
                // more logic here 
            })
            .then((data) => {
                // I build a parameter string here I want the table component to be rendered with. This is important to the app
                var paramString = `.....`; 

                this.props.onFiltersSelected(data, paramString);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I read the docs for react-router, but wasn't clear on how the `history` works exactly. I understand a route needs to be pushed to the history, but how do I tackle it since the form component won't have access to `history`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to get access to history...

Here's what you can do:

1. Create a file called `history.js` in the `src` and put this code
   in there:

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

   export default createBrowserHistory();
   ```
2. import `Router` not `BrowserRoouter` in your `index.js` and use
   that instead. Also `import history from './history'` and pass it as
   a prop to `Router` like so:

   ```
   import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'; // not BroswerRouter

       ReactDOM.render(
         <Router history={history}>
           <App />
         </Router>,
         document.getElementById('root')
       );
   ```

Now you have history available to you anywhere you want. **Just import history into any component and use history.push()**

For example in your `OnDemandProductSearch` just import history

```
import history from './history';

class OnDemandProductSearch extends React.Component {
    {......}
    
    onFiltersSelected = (products, queryParams) => {
        this.setState({
            products: products,
            isSearched: true
        });
        
        history.push({
            search: queryParams
        });
    };

    {......}
};
```

Comment: So I understand you're asking me to use `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter` and control `history` as a prop. But the code above is breaking something. It doesnt render anything. The URL changes, but the `OnDemandProductSearch` component doesn't show up. I tried a log in the `componentDidMount`

Comment: What does the URL change to?

Comment: I have a `Header` component that links to `OnDemandProductSearch`. When I click it, the route changes to `/onDemandProductSearch` (as defined in my `App`). But nothing renders. Basically, I see the problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707885/browserrouter-vs-router-with-history-push despite using `Router`.
I cannot navigate from within the app, but it will render if I enter it in the browser directly.

Comment: I'd need to see more code in order to debug... Sounds more like a structural / architecture issue... If you need access to the history API what I mentioned above is a valid way of doing it...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/Q5RA7 You can use this to view the structure. Of course, I've removed some parts, but I've kept all code that I think relevant in there

Comment: There was a minor typo but everything seems to work as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-paper-48hip

Comment: I diffed all files, didn't find any other than the `OnDemandProductSearchForm` being called `OnDemandProductSearchMenu`. This same code in my app doesn't work as expected. If I start with the landing, on clicking `/onDemandProductSearch`, the header disappears. If I load this route in the browser, navigating to `/` makes everything un-render.