# Routing in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

```
import React from 'react'
import {CollectionPage} from '../collection/collection.component'
import './page.shop.scss'
import CollectionOverview from '../../components/collection-overview/component.collection-overview'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (
    <div className='shop-page'>

       <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionPage} />

    </div>
  );
export default ShopPage
```

this works ^

```
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview} />
```

this works as well

```
       <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview} />
       <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
```

this works but when i go to the `${match.path}/:collectionId` it doesn't show anything , can someone point me to 
issue with `<Route path={'${match.path}/:collectionId'}component={CollectionPage} />` cuz it just won't show anything.

Comment: Put `exact` on that last route too.

Comment: Tried it , still not working. @reg

Comment: Make sure you do pass an id and that `CollectionPage` actually renders something.

Comment: I actually even made it static as `shop/jackets`, it still isn't showing the component. And yes, Collection page works perfectly fine if I leave it on the `{${match.path}}` URL .  It works perfectly on `/shop` but not  on `shop/jackets` @reg

Comment: Did you correctly follow the [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) tutorial and wrapped your routes into a `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter` ?

Comment: Yes, I can go to `Localhost:3000/shop` but cannot go to `Localhost:3000/shop/hats`

Comment: What is `collectionId` ? you're saying that `/hats` equal `/:collectionId`? why not just put `${match.path}/hats` since `hats` is clearly not an id here.

Comment: Well, I tried the 'placeholder data' .If it had worked for `/shop/hats` then I could have worked for `{ ${match.path}/:collectionId}` but since it isn't I cannot tell where the error is. Also, `/:collectionId` provides a dynamic way to get what has been entered in the URL .I don't think `/:colletionId` has anything to do with why the route isn't working.

Comment: Try out a different thing. Like replacing `component={CollectionPage}` to `render={() => 'test'}` to see if the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: It isn't working , probably issue with my `<Route>` .`<BrowserRouter>` has been set up , i don't get where the issue is.I can't seem to get even a workaround. @reg

Comment: Integrate `HashRouter` instead and get back to me.

Comment: Won't it break my app .I have multiple components that use the history.push etc. which i believe are provided by the `<Route>`?

Comment: `history.push` also works with `HashRouter`. I sure would know, it works in my current project. If you have any questions, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/hashrouter-vs-browserrouter) out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed the `collectionId` to your url ?

1. if you did not pass the `collectionId` that means it will go on first route
2. if you pass `collectionId` that time it will check if url match or not it will not check strongly.
3. if you want to strongly pass `collectionId` then add the exact keyword to second route.

Comment: I actually even made it static as `shop/jackets` , it still isn't showing  the `component `.Tried adding `exact` as well

Comment: have you used <BrowserRouter> tage in your project main index.js ? because i have tried to generate this issue but in my project it works fine so, check you project index file.

Comment: I had,since `localhost:3000/shop` was working  . rewrote the project and now it works  somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the Q&A.
Please check your routes for the exact path when rendering for the first time. 
For ShopPage in App.js please remove exact path. And keep the exact path in `ShopPage`.

1. In App.js remove exact `<Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />`
2. In `Shop Page` component keep.

```
const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (`
  <div className="shop-page">`
   <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview} />`
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={FinalCollectionPageComp} />
  </div>
`);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use triple backticks ``` (instead of single) to format blocks of code.