# Make multiple pages in ReactJS without using react-dom-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am a beginner in ReactJS web development and I wanted to ask, how can I make multiple pages in ReactJS (for example if I click on a button called "About me" that it will redirect to a different part of the whole site, for example example.com/aboutme) without using react-dom-router?

I don't want to change much in the codes because I already use my App.js as the main page.

Comment: Create your own router? https://ui.dev/build-your-own-react-router/

Comment: You should create your own router to do this. You can follow the tutorial evolutionxbox mentioned.
Also better aproach would be create a Component for homepage(and other pages) and use that component with router so app.js will be cleaner.

Comment: You can give this article a try
https://dilshankelsen.com/react-routing-without-react-router/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your own router with `react-router-dom` to do this. I preferably use [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter).

([What is the difference between HashRouter and BrowserRouter in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/6907782))

Here is a simple example for routing in App.js;

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';
import AboutMe from './components/AboutMe';
import Error404 from './components/Error404';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route key="homepage" exact path={['/', '/homepage']}>
                    <Homepage />
                </Route>

                <Route key="aboutme" exact path="/aboutme">
                    <AboutMe />
                </Route>

                <Route path="*">
                    <Error404 />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

After that when you go `/aboutme` you will see AboutMe component or when you go `/` or `/homepage` you will see Homepage component. If you try to go `/blabla` like this you will see Error404 component.

Comment: Okay I set up everything but if I go to any page it adds a # (http://localhost:3000/#/ or http://localhost:3000/aboutme#/) but its still on the home page

Comment: Can you provide me some code? like on github or codesandbox

Comment: he/she said with out react-router dom

Comment: [Now, instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281425/why-am-i-getting-this-error-export-switch-imported-as-switch-was-not-foun) `Switch`, import and use `Routes`

Answer (score 0):

For example in your render:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>About me</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Function that starts on click:

```
onItemClick: function () {
  this.props.history.push("/about-me");  
}
```