# why am I getting this error: export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: node.js

Keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/routes.jsx 20:37-43
export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-34 23:33-43
```

this is my routes.jsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./containers/App";
import Login from "./containers/Login";
import Register from "./containers/Register";
import ConfirmAddr from "./components/ConfirmAddr";
import ForgotPassword from "./containers/ForgotPassword";
import ResetPassword from "./containers/ResetPassword";
import UserProfile from "./containers/UserProfile";
import NotFound from "./containers/NotFound";
import Messages from "./components/messages";
import Search from "./containers/Search";

export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/users/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/users/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/users/register/:key" component={ConfirmAddr} />
          <Route path="/users/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/reset-password/:key" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
          <Route path="/chat/messages" component={Messages} />
          <Route path="/main/search" component={Search} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and this is my index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import "materialize-css";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MainRouter from "./routes";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./store";
import { getUserData } from "./actions/user-actions";
import AuthService from "./services/AuthService";

const Auth = new AuthService();
const store = configureStore();

if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
  store.dispatch(getUserData(Auth.getConfirm().username));
}

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MainRouter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

not sure what im doing wrong

Answer (score 6):

React-Router has since released a breaking change (from v5 to v6).
One of the things that got removed was the `Switch` component. It should instead be replaced with `Routes` (vide [the docs on upgrading](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)).

So, for example:

```
export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/users/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/users/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/users/register/:key" component={ConfirmAddr} />
          <Route path="/users/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/reset-password/:key" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
          <Route path="/chat/messages" component={Messages} />
          <Route path="/main/search" component={Search} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Becomes

```
export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/users/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/users/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/users/register/:key" component={ConfirmAddr} />
          <Route path="/users/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/reset-password/:key" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Route path="/users/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
          <Route path="/chat/messages" component={Messages} />
          <Route path="/main/search" component={Search} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: if it worked, please mark this as the solution :)