# Error 404 when using GITHUB when I reload the page

Tags: javascript, react-native, github-pages

I am making an E-commerce website with react and I upload the website to Github pages the deployment works ok, but when I click the Nav buttons to go to different parts of the webpage and reload the page, an error 404 appears:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

In the local host it works totally fine. Should I need to deploy my  website as a new project again? I have always upload the websites the same way and I did not have this problem. I actualized my
google browser, can there can be a compatibility problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In "console" tab, inside dev-tools, do you have any additional information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I assume that you are using `create-react-app` with JSX and `react-router-dom` like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="cart" element={<CartPage />} />
    <Route path="settings" element={<SettingsPage />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

Well, HTTP routing in GitHub Pages works differently than using the `npm start` command in your local machine. And fortunately, the developers behind `create-react-app` [have already explained the technical reasons behind this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing):

> If you use routers that use the HTML5 [`pushState` history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) under the hood (for example, [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) with browserHistory), many static file servers will fail. For example, if you used React Router with a route for `/todos/42`, the development server will respond to `localhost:3000/todos/42` properly, but an Express serving a production build as above will not.
>
> This is because when there is a fresh page load for a `/todos/42`, the server looks for the file `build/todos/42` and does not find it. **The server needs to be configured to respond to a request to `/todos/42` by serving `index.html`.**

And yes, **GitHub Pages also counts as a static file server,** and expects that those routes are available as individual static files (e.g. `build/cart.html` for the `/cart` route), and the goal here is to trick GitHub Pages to serve `index.html` instead for all of these routes. However, it is currently **not** possible to fix this issue on the GitHub Pages' side, e.g. by applying the `.htaccess` configuration file (since GitHub Pages doesn't use Apache Web Server) or going to the repository settings on GitHub.

So, what can be done here? The above code snippet uses `<BrowserRouter>`, which is known to be incompatible for hosting with GitHub Pages. And good news, many recommend to **replace the `<BrowserRouter>` into `<HashRouter>`,** which should work in practically all static file servers (see technical reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/what-is-the-difference-between-hashrouter-and-browserrouter-in-react)). There's a [dedicated FreeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/#how-to-handle-routing-using-hashrouter) on how to set up `<HashRouter>` for your React project and publishing it into GitHub Pages.

---

**Note:** Once you have replaced it with `<HashRouter>`, you will need to take care of existing hardcoded paths in HTML/JSX tags as `<HashRouter>` uses good-old HTML anchor/ID tags (e.g. `#menu`). That means `<a href="/cart">` in your React app **must** be replaced with `<a href="#/cart">` (Note the additional hash/`#` character there) or else it will again return a 404.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I am still learning to use react router V6.This helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json add a field name with value

```
"homepage":"."
```

Inside the public as well as  in your build folder create a file as `_redirects` inside it write this code

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I did this also.